# Right click 'Save as' event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I want to see how many user click 'Save as' event using right click but i only track right click not save as event. Kindly help me.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
   var rightclick;
   if (!e) var e = window.event;
   if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
   else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
   alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); 
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mezwF/14/

Comment: You can't, you can capture the right click, but not clicks on the native contextmenu.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact reason why you need to do that but you cant capture click events within the native context menu just like adeneo said. I would prevent default on the context menu and  create my own context menu from simple absolutely positioned DIVs just to have that functionality and register for click events. You can pretty much mimic the native menu-item features by calling window.history.back(),window.history.forward(), window.location.reload() and a couple of others, for the actual saving however, you cant with JavaScript at the moment, but you can force download the page from the server but this needs to happen on the server-side.